# Defining type for function that adds parameters to input type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to define a function that is able to generically add missing parameters to a type, e.g.:

```
interface completeType {
  id: string
  text: string
}

interface otherInterface {
  something: string
  id: string
}

function withDefaultId<T extends {id?: string}>(obj: T): T & {id: string} {
   if(!obj.id) {
      obj.id = "21"
   }
   return obj
}

const completeObject: completeType = withDefaultId({text: "my text"})
```

But this gives me an error that T is not assignable to the output type. How do I phrase this correctly? (Trying to emulate probot-style `context.repo` that adds in certain fields for ya).

Comment: Can you verify that this is a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) where the only errors are the ones you're interested in?  Right now I see that `21` is not a `string` and that `{text: "my text"}` is an object literal and runs afoul of excess property checking that happens on object literals.

Comment: super fair point! that said - why doesn't it work with the object literal? (My ideal is to be able to support a function that adds to object literal without more typing)

Comment: Look into [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  The handbook mentions a few ways to turn it off; in your case you might make it `T extends {id?: string; [k: string]: unknown}`... but it depends on use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't narrow the type of an optional property to a required one upon assignment.  This is as designed, although it is sometimes frustrating.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#29827](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29827) for some discussion.  And in general, property writes don't narrow the type of the whole object, see [microsoft/TypeScript#35086](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35086) for some discussion.  Control flow narrowing on assignment only happens when you assign a value to a variable/property of a union type, and it only happens to the particular variable/property you're setting.  All of this means that `obj.id = "21"` doesn't modify the type of `obj` as seen by the compiler.

The simplest way to do deal with this is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that you're sure you are returning the right type.  You know you've made the `id` property required, so you can just assert that it's true:

```
function withDefaultId<T extends { id?: string }>(obj: T): T & { id: string } {
    if (!obj.id) {
        obj.id = "21"
    }
    return obj as T & { id: string };
}
```

Less straightforward is to change your implementation to a form the compiler already sees as returning the right type.  For example, something like:

```
function withDefaultId<T extends { id?: string }>(obj: T): T & { id: string } {
    return Object.assign(obj, { id: obj.id || "21" });
}
```

That should give you a similar result (assuming `obj` doesn't have some dynamic [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) for the `id` property, or has any other magic weirdness going on.  But now there's no compiler error.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQewLYAcA2FIAqAnligN4CwAUMrcsACYBcyAzmFKAObV3KQAPMC3acQPKgF9q1UJFiIUaMAAtoASXDR4SZJRp1WmfCu4iO3XnUbmxE6VRmOqMAK4gEYYGhDIA7sCqACIQ8K44YOoMADwEyBBCECAMrHr0DAD8ttzIkgB8ABRoAEYAViwEAJQVyABkaTZsFuK5ela0wDDIBQCEJaUAdIyVbQZ8tP1DDMgAvMgARABMAIzz7bnrUPiuUL79yHCpcfVk6dktkgDc1A7Ubh5ePshoUACycETFELHxicmpp0YWSadgANMgANoAa3OXAAuix3FCQGg-L58kUyhVqshjg1mCCcpJRnwtmAdr4APJlCCeAaHVjALggTGlcGAgmTRjIAA+PIWK3muUq1ykTmo6BARjwAxwaC4RTeHy+BVOcBYy3BjXmQsklUq4ucTgA9MbJexUJhcPgINTSrThJbsHhCCQUHMAsFQnBwpEGKr+AlHfMMERA0JdZUgA)

Comment: Perfect - thanks! :D  Just to clarify: the `as` format supports any setters correctly? (I think it's clearer to the reader than `Object.assign`)

Comment: The `as` method is sort of a general-purpose way to stop the compiler from complaining when you are sure something you are doing is type safe.  But it shifts the responsibility for maintaining type safety from the compiler to you.  So if you make a mistake (say, you check `if (obj.id)` instead of `if (!obj.id)`) the compiler still won't complain, and now you've lied to the compiler about the types.  Which can easily bite you down the line.  Type assertions are best used sparingly, when there's no easy  type-safe alternative.